# Broken Image from blob data PHP?

Tags: php, blob

Ok so I know this question has been asked but I still could not figure out what was wrong with my code.

I am trying to upload an image to a database and store it as a blob so it can output on the page. Everything works, everything is stored in the mysql database but when I try to echo out the blob it gives me a broken image. Here is my code.

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file)) {
echo "Please select image.";
} else {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size==FALSE) {
    echo 'that is not an image.';
    } else {
     if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image')")) {
      echo "Problem uploading image";
     } else {
      $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
      echo "Image uploaded.<p />Your image:<p /><img src=ShowPics.php?id=$lastid>";
     }
    }

}



?>


<form action="Photosite.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And my PHP page

```
 <?php

 $id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
 $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id=$id");
 $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
 $image = $image['image'];


 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 echo $image;

?>
```

Any help appreciated??? I just do not get why i am getting a broken image...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks will do, I was aware of those but just haven't got around to them.

Answer (score 3):

You have a space on the first line, before `<?php`. If it's like that in your code, that gives the problem. Nothing should be outputted before you echo the image.

If you're sure that the current file is correct you can do

```
<?php
ob_start();

// do stuff

ob_end_clean();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

With this workaround, the image is show if the blob in de DB is correct.

You can check the BLOB in [phpmyadmin using transformations](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html).

---

P.S. `addslashes` only helps if you put the value between slashes, so

```
$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id='$id'");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that it's a [hidden BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character at the start of one of your PHP files.

Please can you change

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

to

```
//header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo substr($image, 0, 20);
```

And see if it looks like the start of a valid jpeg file - something like 'ÿØÿàJFIF'

If instead it has 'ï»¿' at the start, it means that at least one of your PHP files has the byte order marker at the start of it, and it needs to be removed.

Comment: Ok I did that and I noticed nothing changed when I ran Photosite.php (the first code). So I turned the whole ShowPics.php into /* */ notes and still nothing changed. So something in ShowPics.php must be wrong or the img src code on the first part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i also shared in this your problem of broken image until i read this post from this site [http://www.boogiejack.com/html-help/html-help-broken-image.html]. The first observation helped me to go through the names i used in creating my table fields and i was shocked to see that i gave a wrong name for my table fields. After correcting them, my image started showing, Thank God, was i happy full of joy. Please look over the fields of your table, maybe you misspelt it as i did. :)