# Broken image retrieved from Mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I upload image and store its path or directory to database that is successfully stored but now when i retrieved image from database broken image load here plz help me out thanks in advance. I already checked these stackoverflow questions **[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669035/broken-image-from-blob-data-php)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823084/broken-file-icon-retrieving-image-from-database-php-and-mysql)  and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669035/broken-image-from-blob-data-php)**

My display script

```html
<?php
include("configdb.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  `images_tbl` ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
   
}
?>
```

and uploading script

```html
<?php
include("configdb.php");
    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
     case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "../Photos/".$imagename;
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";    
mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error($conn)); 
}else{
   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
}
}

echo "<img src='displayupload.php?id=7' width='200 px' height='200px' />";

?>;
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere in your "display" code, that you show your image(s) that you retrieve from the database. You only iterate the result but never use $row result ? ..

Comment: check it while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
?>

Comment: you are missing a <img src="$row['image_path']"> in your display code as far as i can see

Comment: i am displaying it in 2nd script i upload echo "<img src='displayupload.php?id=7' width='200 px' height='200px' />";

Comment: you are not displaying it on your display script

Comment: i am displaying it in 2nd script i upload echo "<img src='displayupload.php?id=7' width='200 px' height='200px' />";

Comment: you're displaying nothing in your displayupload.php snippet. it's just a while loop with nothing being echoed out. your code is incomplete.

Comment: Firstly your id variable you use when calling displayupload.php is not used in your display code. Your DISPLAY code should echo the path retrieved from your database not just iterate all the results on an empty loop

Comment: Done thank you all for your kind responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```html
<?php
include("configdb.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  `images_tbl` ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
 
 
 
 
 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn,$sql);
        header("Content-type: " . $row["images_id"]);
        echo $row["images_path"];
         }
    mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

and display it from the path where you have saved or stored that like

```html
<?php
include("configdb.php");
    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
     case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "../Photos/".$imagename;
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (`images_path`,`submission_date`) VALUES
('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";    
mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysqli_error($conn)); 
}else{
   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
}
}

echo "<img src='../Photos/$imagename' width='200 px' height='200px' />";

?>;
```